# C/ HTML - Printing the username and password from an HTML Form

Tags: html, c, cgi

We were asked to create a login page using HTML, C/CGI and CSS. I wanted to start with the basics, HTML and C/CGI first so I created this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char *data;
char *user;
char *password;
printf("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
printf("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Welcome!</title></head><body>");
data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
   if (data) {
       sscanf(data,"user=%s&password=%s", &user, &password);
       printf("Hello Mr./Ms. %s\n",user);
       printf("You entered your password %s\n",password);
      }
printf("<form action='http://localhost/inch.html'>");
printf("<input type=submit value='Compute'>");
printf("</body></html>");
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

However, the compiler is showing me this problem:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3
>   has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
>        sscanf(data,"user=%s&password=%s", &user, &password);

Also, the HTML is showing me Error 500.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm fairly new at this HTML/CGI thing, and I would appreciate help along the way. Thanks!

Comment: You define some variables that are pointers, but you never make them point anywhere. That is wrong and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for your warning, did you actually *read* it? It tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) needs a pointer to char:

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

Try this:

```
char user[100];
char password[100];
// ...
sscanf(data,"user=%s&password=%s", user, password);
```